# Tragedy with no one to blame

Tags: word-request

I've read this term about literary criticism and it's rather an awkward expression in my mother language. So I suppose it must be translated from a foreign language. It is used to describe a tragedy with no one to blame. Could anyone help me to find this term? I consulted the dictionary and google but nothing valuable were found.

P.S. the storyline of the play is: a young princess and a boy were friends. The boy irritated the king and was killed. The king prohibited anyone to bury the boy. But as best friends, the princess buried the boy anyway(with her toy shovel). So the king has to execute the princess. So, no one is guilty, but this is a true tragedy.

btw does anyone know what is this play called? I remember that this is an adaptation of a classic play.

edit: I think the princess killed herself after being immured. I'm afraid I can't remember the story as its exact form.

more on the play: I think everyone died at last except for the royal guards who didn't care.

Comment: *Blame it on bad-luck* - *Bayside

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a tragedy, but (at least in a western mindset) it seems quite easy to hand out blame. The boy is to blame for irritating the king, the king is to blame for making a stupid rule, the princess is to blame for breaking the rule, and the king once more for sticking to it. One could argue that all character shared in the blame, but I find it hard to conclude that _no_ one was to blame.

Comment: @oerkelens maybe all of them have their share of guilt, but I don't think the boy and the princess deserve to die, and the king doesn't deserve to lose his daughter. They're just sticking to their principles(a king has to be obeyed, and one has to be true to their friends no matter what, but I can't justify for what the boy did). Besides, I may not have remembered the plot correctly. For instance, the king would be less guilty if he just confined the princess in her room, and then she killed herself.

Comment: I will not go into details about who has more guilt, but it seems that we are talking about human decisions that lead clearly to the tragedy here. Whether they deserve to die or not does not change whether they are responsible for the results of their actions. A tragedy without blame would - for me - imply something like the tragedy of Oedipus, where everything is done to avoid the prophecy from coming true, but Fate decides differently. That would, by the way, simply be referred to as a tragedy.

Comment: Your question reminds me of an "accidental tragedy".

Comment: @oerkelens I blame it all to Fate :). I specifically remembered the play mentioned above was famous for its plot that everyone made a perfectly reasonable choice under the circumstance, but the result was sad (still, I can't justify the boy's behavior. I guess the author could)

Comment: @DamkerngT. but this is not accidental...the term would be translated word-for-word to "no responsible-person tragedy". Maybe it's not English?

Comment: Well, I would argue that killing your daughter's friend is _never_ a reasonable choice, imposing a death penalty on burial is _never_ a reasonable choice, and killing your daughter is _never_ a reasonable choice. But then, these things _do_ tend to be culturally influenced :)

Comment: In a classical (Greek) tragedy, there is normally _no human_ that carries responsibility. So the English version of what you look for would be _tragedy_. However, I suspect a lot of people will have a very hard time applying the _no responsibility_ idea to an arbitrarily murdering, possessive potentate making one terrible decision after the other ;)

Comment: @oerkelens I think the play is from ancient Greek and was adapted by a French author. But I forgot the plot above is the original one or the adapted one. I think the main storyline is correct, but the toy shovel part (which implies there's an adult within the young princess), and the part where the king's soliloquy reveals his sentiments (which implies he's an unwilling child put to higher places than he could handle) should be credited to the adaptation

Comment: I will try to give more information about the play

Comment: The toy shovel part somehow does not ring Greek to me, so I guess that is an adaptation indeed :) I'm trying to figure out which play it is as well now :)

Comment: The play is *Antigone*, and the version you're talking about is probably that of Jean Anouilh.

Comment: From [this webpage](https://sites.google.com/site/evansenglishnipmuc/caesar-resources/freytag-aristotle-and-tragedy), "The word _hamartia_ is often described as a hero’s “tragic flaw”. The word hamartia is rooted from the word hamartanein and has a wide meaning of ignorant, mistaken, or accidental wrongdoing. The hamartia, as stated, is seen as an error in judgment or unwitting mistake is applied to the actions of the hero. However the word hamartia is not acutely defined and doesn’t have a meaning that is set in stone. The hamartia tragedy is common in a lot of Greek literature and plays."

Comment: The king in that play loses his son and his wife, because he punished his son's fiancee and her brother. (She wanted to bury her brother). Hamartia may well be applied to Creon's stubbornness, but I would certainly not see Creon as "not to blame". The gods punish him, and he assumes responsibility for the tragic events, so there certainly is "blame".

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks! It seems that I invented some weird plots here.

Comment: @oerkelens yes, I agree that there're plenty to blame when I see the real plot, not the one I made up. And actually I found the article that caused all this confusion following StoneyB's lead. It's written by a well-known author, who has a fame of inventing terms that sound exotic to make his essays seem sophisticated. And the "no one's to blame" theory is his own idea, inspired Hegel's interpretation that the play is set around the conflict between the valid claims of conscience and law.

Comment: @oerkelens and his article is about Jean Anouilh's adaptation, and he interprets this version as the conflict between the irresoluteness of adults and the boldness of the young. I've never read both versions(will do), and the critic left out the plots that don't serve his argument.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about literary criticism and unlikely to be helpful to English Language Learners.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung when I first asked this question it could be on-topic, but now it's totally off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the word *hubris*, which doesn't quite mean "no one to blame," but it could be roughly defined as "no one to blame **but yourself**."

Slide 5 of [***Elements of Greek tragedy and the tragic hero***](http://www.slideshare.net/cafeharmon/elements-of-greek-tragedy-and-the-tragic-hero#) mentions:

[image]

Interestingly enough, on the next slide, the slideshow’s creator mentions the play you are describing:

[image]

I don't know if this is the work you were after or not; it's hard to tell from the information given.